# Top menu without flex, without calc(...) for legacy support

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to do a top menu with a 1px border. **How to have the #mid `div` use the full middle width (so that the bottom-border goes close to #right) ?**

I'm looking for a solution without `flex`, without `width: calc(...)`, because it's not supported on some devices I did tests on (legacy support needed).

```css
* { margin:0; padding: 0; }
.left { float:left; width: 155px; height: 60px; border-right: 1px solid #dedede; border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede; }
.mid { float:left; height: 60px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede; display:inline-block; }
.right { float: right; width: 40%; height: 60px; border-left: 1px solid #dedede; border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede; }
```

```html
<div>
<div class="left">aa</div>
<div class="mid">aa</div>
<div class="right">bb</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the display:table layout properties can help you to start with : (=>IE8)

table shrinks/expands to hold content. that's why `.mid` will use as much space avalaible squizing others table-cell elements being less than the 100% width set in CSS. Mind that If content is wider than the tabled container, it will grow over the 100% width.

```css
* { margin:0; padding: 0;box-sizing:border-box; }
.tb {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  border:solid 1px;
  }
.tb > div {
  display:table-cell;
  border:inherit ;
  }
.mid { width:100%; }
```

```html
<div class="tb">
<div class="left">aa</div>
<div class="mid">aa</div>
<div class="right">bb</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="tb">
<div class="left">longer</div>
<div class="mid">aa</div>
<div class="right">longer</div>
</div>
```

or float properties  and block formating context :(to include IE6 add zoom:1; aside overflow)

- `.left` and `.right` are to `float` and **be first in the flow**.
- middle will come in between, BFC will avoid `.mid` to lay under floating elements.

```css
div div {
  border:solid 1px ;
  overflow:hidden;/* modify BFC */
  }
.left  {
  float:left;
  }
.right {
  float:right
    }
```

```html
    <div >
    <div class="left">aa</div>
     <div class="right">bb</div>     
    <div class="mid">mid</div>
    </div>
<hr/><div >
    <div class="left">longer</div>
     <div class="right">longer</div>     
    <div class="mid">mid</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @GCyrillus! Your trick of swapping order in the HTML part (`<div class="left"> ...  <div class="right"> ... <div class="mid">`)  solved it!
But then it seems difficult to do this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228226/swap-div-position-with-media-query Maybe you would have an idea?