# Swap div position with media query

Tags: html, css, css-float, media-queries

When browser width becomes under 600px, I'd like such a position change, thanks to a media query :

[image]

**It seems that this would need to swap div position. Is this possible with CSS?**

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#a { float: left; background-color: red; width: 150px; }
#b { background-color: blue; }
#c { float: right; width: 40%; background-color: yellow; }
@media (max-width: 600px) { 
        /* ... */
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div id="a">a</div>
   <div id="c">c</div>
   <div id="b">b</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to reset the float or width properties.

Do mind the BFC block formating context when you deal with floating and non floatting elements.

> http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#a {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
}
#b {
  background-color: blue;
}
#c {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #c {    
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="a">a float</div>
  <div id="c">c float or not</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is my last problem @GCyrillyus : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239774/full-width-input-in-a-div ... Maybe you'll have an idea :)

Comment: @Basj see dippas answer updated from http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/WwWPwP/ should do what you finally look for

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible with CSS. In fact, it's quite easy with flexbox, which is designed for such a task.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;                    /* establish flex container */
}

#a {
  flex: 0 0 150px;                  /* don't grow, don't shrink, fixed at 150px width */
  background-color: red;
}
#b {
  flex: 1;                          /* consume all available free space in the row */
  background-color: aqua;
}
#c {
  flex: 0 0 40%;                    /* don't grow, don't shrink, fixed at 40% width */
  background-color: yellow;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #container { flex-wrap: wrap; }        /* allow flex items to wrap */
  #b { flex-basis: calc(100% - 150px); } /* take full width less width of #a */
  #c { flex-grow: 1; }                   /* consumer all available free space in the row */
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><!-- children ordered chronologically; no need to reverse order -->
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
  <div id="c">c</div>
</div>
```

---

*To learn more about flexbox visit:*

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)
- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ~ MDN
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ~ CSS-Tricks
- [What the Flexbox?!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu8EoSxDXHP7xj_y6NIAhy0wuCd4uVdid) ~ YouTube video tutorial

---

*Benefits of flexbox:*

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats and tables, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

*Browser support:*

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).