# Full width input in a div

Tags: html, css, css-float

Is it possible, without `width: calc(...)` nor `flex` (for legacy support) to have the input `#what` to use full width of its parent `#b` ?

**Note:** Run the code snippet in full-screen and re-dimension the browser `width` to see the media query in action.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#a {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
}
#b {
  background-color: blue;
}
#c {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#icon {
  background-color: black;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#what {}@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #c {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="a">a float</div>
  <div id="c">c float or not</div>
  <div id="b">
    <div id="icon">s</div>
    <input id="what" value="Blah" />
  </div>
</div>
```